# How to set range for year

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, frontend

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, 
                 "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", 
                 new { @class = "form-control", 
                       id = startDateId, 
                       type = "date",
                       @readonly = "readonly" })        

<label class="error">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StartDate)</label>
```

I want validation for 1990-2020 years. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a CustomAttribue. As you have for example [Required], tou can create your own (custom).

See the documentation for more info: [Writing Custom Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes)

For a range dates control, you will something like:

```
public class MyRangeDatesAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
  public MyRangeDatesAttribute ()
    : base(typeof(DateTime), 
            DateTime.Now.AddYears(-6).ToShortDateString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) 
  { } 
}
```

How use it:

```
[MyRangeDates]
public DateTime StartDate{ get; set; }
```

Another solution is using the deafult Range Attribue:

```
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "01/01/1990", "01/01/2020", ErrorMessage="Your error message!")]
```